# Linking External Libraries in Android Studio (gradle)

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk

I am using Android Studio. I added all the header files in the `jni`folder and also added the libraries in the `jniLibs` folder and also i added the path in the `build.gradle` file.

```
sourceSets.main {
jni.srcDir 'src/main/jni'
jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
}
```

but I am getting `undefined reference error`. I searched on net and most solutions are to block automatic `ndk-build` call and edit the `Android.mk` file and then running `ndk-build` call from terminal. I want to link the external libraries in the `build.gradle` file.

Secondly i am getting `undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'` error. I linked the library

```
ldLibs "stdc++"
```

but still i am getting error. I am using cross compiled libraries and header files and i think i need to link the libraries provided by cross compiler. So i  did like this

```
ldLibs "/home/xx/xx/xx/xx/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/stdc++"
```

but still getting error. Any solution about it?

Answer (score 0):

To declare the STL in `build.gradle`, use:

```
stl    "gnustl_static"
```

`ldLibs` is reserved for other libs.

Extract from my `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        moduleName "MyModule"
        cFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
        ldLibs "atomic -llog"
        stl    "gnustl_static"
    }
}
```